# What is the 'name' in pandas.DataFrame.columns?

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

When I execute a pivot on a pandas dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two','two'],
    'bar': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'baz': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'zoo': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'q', 'w', 't']})

df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values='baz')


>>> bar A   B   C
    foo         
    one 1   2   3
    two 4   5   6
```

Which has these columns,

```
df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values='baz').columns

>>> Index(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object', name='bar')
```

My question is, what does `name=bar` part mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.html)

> name : object
>
> Name to be stored in the index

In your example, it's the name of the `pandas.Index` that is used as the column name.

The name attribute becomes useful in some cases, for instance if you have a multiindex, you can refer to the level of the index by it's name:

```
>>> df
idx1  1  2  3 # <- column header 1
idx2  a  b  c # <- column header 2
vals  5  4  6

>>> df.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]],
           names=['idx1', 'idx2'])

>>> df.columns.get_level_values('idx1')
Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64', name='idx1')
>>> df.columns.get_level_values('idx2')
Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object', name='idx2')
```